# Drupal 7: Webform: Send Email Custom PHP on Webform submit

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I have a webform and I want to send an email to a user on submit action on this webform.

Note: I do not want to use the inbuild emails module for webform as it has some limitations related to the functionality that i want to achieve. 
Hence I want to send a test email on Submit action via a custom PHP.

I know how to write PHP for a webform but I need some guidance on how to use it for sending emails.

Also I want to send emails on submit action only if user selects a select option on this form.

How can I do this? Please help I am stuck on this for a long time now.

Comment: This hook will be called when a new Webform submission is inserted: http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_insert/7. You may also be interested in using Rules (http://drupal.org/project/rules) to achieve this through the UI.

Comment: Thanks ! So I just have to insert the code given on that link into my form and then its done?

Comment: Well I just figured out that if I insert php code onto my webform, it clears out all other fields that I had added on this form :(
any idea ?

Comment: What do you mean by "insert php code onto my webform"? *Where* are you inserting this code? The hook should be inserted into a custom module, which is nothing more than a `mymodule.module` file inside a similarly names folder in `sites/all/modules`.

Comment: Instead of hooks, I am going through rules.
So I created one rule for sending email. The trigger condition is "After a webform has been submitted" and I added an action "Execute custom PHP code" and the code is as follows:





    $message = array(
    'to' => 'example@abc.com',
    'subject' =>'test sub',
    'body' =>'test body',
    'headers' => array('From' => 'aaa@bbb.com'),
    );

    drupal_mail_send($message);


Is this correct ?

Comment: Instead of "Execute Custom PHP Code", you could just run the action under System that read something like "Send an email." If you install the Mailsystem (http://drupal.org/project/mailsystem) and MIME Mail (http://drupal.org/project/mimemail) modules, you'll get an option to send an HTML email, which can include CCs, BCCs (I think) and attachments. It's strongly disouraged to enter PHP code through the UI instead of through your codebase (custom modules, etc) since you cannot version code entered through the UI, it's difficult to debug, can introduce security vulnerabilities, etc.

Comment: All right I can add send email action.
But I am not able to access the webform submitted data. Any idea?
Another Problem is that I need to send emails only IF the user had selected a particular select option on the webform. And I am not able to put this condition as well.

Comment: Ask this question on drupal.stackexchange.com.